# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints returns width beyond the constraint?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-text, sizewithfont

In my app, I need change some view's size dynamically according to its text content. At first I use `-sizeWithFont` to do the string measurement. There's lots of measurement in my app to do, so I put the `-sizeWithFont` into a background, since apple's documentation saying "In iOS 10.4 and later, you may use the methods described in this class extension from secondary threads in your app and not just from the main thread. ". However, the truth is that this method will call some WebCore function which is not thread-safe, so the app will crash. This bug is already been filed but still not fixed. (some questions about this e.g. [sizeWithFont in MultiThread Crash!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527877/sizewithfont-in-multithread-crash))

Since I can't put the measurement into main thread due to performance, I'm trying the CoreText framework. I first create a corresponding `NSAttributedString` for my string, then use some CT function to do the measurement. I know that in iOS 6, there're very simple API like the `-size` can do this job, but I can't use them due to the compatibility. So I have to call some low-level function like the `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints()` or `CTFramesetterCreateFrame()`, but I found that these **CT methods sometimes didn't respect my constraint**. **For example, if I set a `CGSize(200, CGFLOAT_MAX)` for the `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints()`, which should means there's a constraint in the width, but acturally it will return some size that have a larger width like 205.** The same thing happens with the `CTFramesetterCreateFrame()`. If I call it and then call the `CTFrameGetLines()`, I sometimes get a line count less than it should be because some line's width is beyond 200px and containing more words than it should be.

Sorry for long description, here's my questions:

1. maybe use the CT framework to measure a simple string is a waste, so
   is there a way to make -sizeWithFont can be used in a background
   safely?
2. if the behavior of `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints()` is by design, is
   there any way to make the CT function strictly obey my constraint?
   If not, how can I measure the strings with a fixed width and the
   linebreakmode is wordwrapping?

Comment: Use the editor to format your text a bit better. This is a wall of text and its hard to actually see what you need help with! :)

Comment: No worries as a new user its sometimes hard to know what's what! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(), and before returning result size try to set result.width parameter to the width from your constraints size.